# how shall I calculate "predict" by hand after "GaussianHMM.fit() " instead of "predict()"?

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I do as below:

```
hmm=GaussianHMM(n_components=5,covariance_type='diag',n_iter=500).fit(X)
```

Now I want to predict 'x';and I know I can do it by code: hmm.predict(x);
but shall I see the some parameters of "hmm" and calculate it by hand ?

The simple axample, "X" is a vector (10000 rows, 1 column); then after running codes:

```
hmm=GaussianHMM(n_components=5,covariance_type='diag',n_iter=500).fit(X)
```

, I think "some parameters" should be like as below:

```
a1<x<b1: ab1
a2<x<b2: ab2
a3<x<b3: ab3
a4<x<b4: ab4
a5<x<b5: ab5
```

so how shall I get above from hmm?